# How to find sizes of files in bzip2 archive without unpacking?

Tags: linux, archive, bzip2

I have 1.4GB .bzip2 archive and when try unzip it, I get this error:

> bzip2: I/O or other error, bailing out.  Possible reason follows.
>
> bzip2: No space left on device

But I have 13GB free space into current partition.

How to get size of unzipped file without unzipping?

Answer (score 1):

You'll still have to "spend" the time of running the decompression algorithm, but you can redirect the character stream to the `wc -c` (Word count characters) utility. i.e.

```
  bunzip2 -c bigFile.bz2 | wc -c
```

IHTH

Comment: For `bzip2`, the following worked for me:

`bzip2 -dc bigFile.bz2 | wc -c`

Answer (score -1):

You can use below command to get the bz2 file (compressed using bzip2 compressor) related details.

```
ls -ahl filename.[extension].bz2
```

Comment: @konstov knows the 13 GB filesize of the bz2 archive - he want's to know the unzipped size